# PyQt5 how to show keyinput in QLineEdit?

Tags: python, pyqt

I am trying to get a readonly QLineEdit in a second window to show the name of the key pressed. For example if I press key `a` it shows `a Key` and if I press the spacebar it shows `SpaceBar Key`. I searched the net for solutions but most of them were about how to close a window when a certain key is pressed.

I have a working sample made with tkinter linked below.
https://gist.github.com/sangonkim/e397c420d93485f3896f9440bbcc77aa

I made 2 simple windows with QDesigner for the question.

```
from PyQt5 import QtCore, QtGui, QtWidgets

class Ui_MainWindow(object):
    def setupUi(self, MainWindow):
        MainWindow.setObjectName("MainWindow")
        MainWindow.resize(347, 259)
        self.centralwidget = QtWidgets.QWidget(MainWindow)
        self.centralwidget.setObjectName("centralwidget")
        self.pushButton = QtWidgets.QPushButton(self.centralwidget)
        self.pushButton.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(110, 110, 121, 28))
        self.pushButton.clicked.connect(self.connect)
        self.pushButton.setObjectName("pushButton")
        MainWindow.setCentralWidget(self.centralwidget)

        self.retranslateUi(MainWindow)
        QtCore.QMetaObject.connectSlotsByName(MainWindow)

    def connect(self):
        self.window = QtWidgets.QMainWindow()
        self.ui = Ui_MainWindow2()
        self.ui.setupUi(self.window)
        self.window.show()

    def retranslateUi(self, MainWindow):
        _translate = QtCore.QCoreApplication.translate
        MainWindow.setWindowTitle(_translate("MainWindow", "MainWindow"))
        self.pushButton.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "To next window"))


class Ui_MainWindow2(object):
    def setupUi(self, MainWindow):
        MainWindow.setObjectName("MainWindow")
        MainWindow.resize(384, 261)
        self.centralwidget = QtWidgets.QWidget(MainWindow)
        self.centralwidget.setObjectName("centralwidget")
        self.lineEdit = QtWidgets.QLineEdit(self.centralwidget)
        self.lineEdit.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(130, 100, 113, 21))
        self.lineEdit.setReadOnly(True)
        self.lineEdit.setObjectName("lineEdit")
        MainWindow.setCentralWidget(self.centralwidget)

        self.retranslateUi(MainWindow)
        QtCore.QMetaObject.connectSlotsByName(MainWindow)

    def retranslateUi(self, MainWindow):
        _translate = QtCore.QCoreApplication.translate
        MainWindow.setWindowTitle(_translate("MainWindow", "MainWindow"))


if __name__ == "__main__":
    import sys
    app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
    Main_Window = QtWidgets.QMainWindow()
    ui = Ui_MainWindow()
    ui.setupUi(Main_Window)
    Main_Window.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

I've tried adding

```
def keyinput(self, event):
    print(event.key())
```

to `Ui_MainWindow2`see if I can capture the key I an typing. But it does not work.

And also tried

```
def keyinput(self, event):
    self.lineEdit.setText(str(event.key()))
```

And failed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

into setupUi add:

```
MainWindow.keyPressEvent = self.newOnkeyPressEvent
```

and define function:

```
def newOnkeyPressEvent(self, event):

    key = event.key()
    modifiers = int(event.modifiers())
    keyname = QtGui.QKeySequence(modifiers + key).toString()
    print(keyname)
    self.lineEdit.setText(str(keyname))
```

full code:

```
from PyQt5 import QtCore, QtGui, QtWidgets


class Ui_MainWindow(object):
    def setupUi(self, MainWindow):
        MainWindow.setObjectName("MainWindow")
        MainWindow.resize(347, 259)
        self.centralwidget = QtWidgets.QWidget(MainWindow)
        self.centralwidget.setObjectName("centralwidget")
        self.pushButton = QtWidgets.QPushButton(self.centralwidget)
        self.pushButton.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(110, 110, 121, 28))
        self.pushButton.clicked.connect(self.connect)
        self.pushButton.setObjectName("pushButton")
        MainWindow.setCentralWidget(self.centralwidget)

        self.retranslateUi(MainWindow)
        QtCore.QMetaObject.connectSlotsByName(MainWindow)

    def connect(self):
        self.window = QtWidgets.QMainWindow()
        self.ui = Ui_MainWindow2()
        self.ui.setupUi(self.window)
        self.window.show()

    def retranslateUi(self, MainWindow):
        _translate = QtCore.QCoreApplication.translate
        MainWindow.setWindowTitle(_translate("MainWindow", "MainWindow"))
        self.pushButton.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "To next window"))



class Ui_MainWindow2(object):
    def setupUi(self, MainWindow):
        MainWindow.setObjectName("MainWindow")
        MainWindow.resize(384, 261)
        self.centralwidget = QtWidgets.QWidget(MainWindow)
        self.centralwidget.setObjectName("centralwidget")
        self.lineEdit = QtWidgets.QLineEdit(self.centralwidget)
        self.lineEdit.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(130, 100, 113, 21))
        self.lineEdit.setReadOnly(True)
        self.lineEdit.setObjectName("lineEdit")
        MainWindow.setCentralWidget(self.centralwidget)

        MainWindow.keyPressEvent = self.newOnkeyPressEvent

        self.retranslateUi(MainWindow)
        QtCore.QMetaObject.connectSlotsByName(MainWindow)

    def retranslateUi(self, MainWindow):
        _translate = QtCore.QCoreApplication.translate
        MainWindow.setWindowTitle(_translate("MainWindow", "MainWindow"))


    def newOnkeyPressEvent(self, event):

        key = event.key()
        modifiers = int(event.modifiers())
        keyname = QtGui.QKeySequence(modifiers + key).toString()
        print(keyname)
        self.lineEdit.setText(str(keyname))

if __name__ == "__main__":
    import sys
    app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
    Main_Window = QtWidgets.QMainWindow()
    ui = Ui_MainWindow()
    ui.setupUi(Main_Window)
    Main_Window.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

Comment: Thank you, it works the way I want. But it seems to have some problem. The program crashes when I enter left shift, ctrl, win, alt and right shift, alt and shows a blank with right ctrl and shows no input for prtsc, scrLk, del, home, end keys.